# If $H\leqslant G$ and $K\leqslant G$, is it always true that $HK\leqslant G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The $HK$ set is defined as the set $\left\{hk\,|\,h\in H,k\in K\right\}$
My guess is that this is not necessarily true. If we use the two step subgroup test and pick $h_1k_1$ and $h_2k_2$ from $HK$, then $h_1k_1h_2k_2$ is not necessarily an element of $HK$ unless $h$ and $k$ commute. That is, when $H\trianglelefteq G$ and $K\trianglelefteq G$.

Comment: Hint: Say that HK is a subgroup of G is equivalent to say HK=KH.

Comment: Commutativity is a much stronger condition than you need.

Comment: You only need that ONE of them is normal.

Answer (score 4):

It is sufficient that *one* of the subgroups is normal. For example, if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G,$ then $h_1k_1h_2k_2=h_1h_2'k_1k_2$ for some $h_2'\in H.$

In general, $HK$ will be a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $HK=KH.$ (Note that this will occur whenever at least one of $H,K$ is normal, but neither actually *has* to be.) If $HK=KH,$ proving that $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ is straightforward. Suppose that $HK\ne KH.$ Then there exist $h\in H,k\in K$ such that $kh\notin HK.$ But $(kh)^{-1}=h^{-1}k^{-1}\in HK$ and $\left((kh)^{-1}\right)^{-1}=kh,$ so $HK$ fails to be a subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  For a specific example, take $G = S_3$, $H = \langle (1,2)\rangle$ and $K=\langle (1,3)\rangle$.  Then $HK = \{ 1, (1,2), (1,3), (1,2,3)\}$, which is not a subgroup of $G$.  You should also be able to see that, in this case, $HK\neq KH$.