# What does $G = G_1 G_2$ mean in group theory?

Tags: group-theory, notation, group-isomorphism

My course notes contain the proposition,

> Let $G$ be a group and $G_1 , G_2$ normal subgroups of $G$ such that $G = G_1 G_2$ and $G_1 \cap G_2 = \{e\}$. Then $G \cong G_1 \times G_2$.

An example is given using $\mathbb{Z}_6 \cong \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 3 \rangle$.

I think I can see that $\mathbb{Z}_6 \cong \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 3 \rangle$ but I don't recognise the notation $G_1 G_2$ and I can't think what $\mathbb{Z}_6 = \langle 2 \rangle \langle 3 \rangle$ should mean.

Could someone explain that ?

**Conjecture :** $G_1G_2:=\{g_1G_2:g_1\in G_1\}$.

Comment: $G_1G_2=\{g_1g_2~|~g_1\in G_1,g_2\in G_2\}$. This should not be confused with product of ideals in a ring. If $R$ is a commutative ring having ideals $I_1$ and $I_2$, then $I_1I_2$ is the collection all expressions of the form $\sum a_{ij}x_iy_j$, where $a_{ij}\in R$, $x_i\in I_1$, and $y_j\in I_2$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141436/let-a-b-be-subgroups-of-a-group-g-prove-ab-is-a-subgroup-of-g-if-and-on) for a definition, in the first comment. We need to assume that $G_1,G_2\subseteq G$, so that the product $g_1\circ g_2=g_1g_2$ makes sense, as the product in $G$. So the product $\langle 2\rangle \langle 3\rangle$ is the product in $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We call it the *set product*. It's from formal languages. It just means

$$XY=\{xy\mid x\in X, y\in Y\}.$$

We evaluate it under the operation of the group, denoted here by concatenation.

For example, in $G=\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2=\{e,a,b,ab\}$, where $a^2=b^2=e$ and $ab=ba$, if $H=\{e,a\}$ and $K=\{e,b\}$, then

$$\begin{align}
HK&=\{hk\mid h\in H, k\in K\}\\
&=\{ee,eb,ae, ab\}\\
&=\{e, b, a, ab\}\\
&=G.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hmm, in my experience, if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, then $HK$ usually means the subgroup generated by $H \cup K$, which includes $\{ hk \mid h\in H, k \in K \}$ but in general might be strictly bigger.  (Of course, with the hypotheses from the OP that $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups, they become equal in this case.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, @DanielSchepler. The question is about what the notation means. I have answered it correctly.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: Not in my experience at all! In fact, a typical theorem/homework problem is "if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups, then $HK$ is a subgroup if and only if $HK=KH$ as sets."  E.g, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4018327/742), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1524826/742); Lemma 2.8 in Herstein's *Topics in Algebra*. I have seen $H\vee K$ used to mean the join (subgroup generated by $H\cup K$) e.g., Hungerford's *Algebra*; or just $H\cup K$ (Hall's *Theory of Groups*) but not $HK$.